# To check Parse.initialize is successful or not

Tags: ionic-framework, parse-server

I am working on an ionic app with parse server.
when I write

```
Parse.initialize(...)
```

I just want to make sure that it has initialized successfully.

Is there a way like

```
if(Parse.initialize(...))
{
   //alert Or log
}
```

OR any other way

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Parse code is written and tested well enough that the initialization is close to always successful. What exactly do you need to check for?

Comment: @cricket_007
Actually after Parse.initialize when I call save to save an object, it gives me error
I posted my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390059/error-cyclic-object-value-while-saving-data-to-parse-server-from-ionic-app wondering that has it initialize sucessfully?

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that error, but since the app knows how to talk to parse, I'd say it's been initialized